# Can 2 GitLab jobs save variables in the same .env file?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have 2 GitLab CI/CD Jobs doing some stuff that generates variables.

For example, the first job saves  in a .env file

```yaml
job1: 
  script:
    - echo "A_VARIABLE=${A_VARIABLE}" >> job.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv:
        - job.env
```

And so does the second job.

```
job2: 
  script:
    - echo "ANOTHER_VARIABLE=${ANOTHER_VARIABLE}" >> job.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv:
        - job.env
```

But can it save to that same job.env file without scratching existing data ?
*I know I can just group the 2 jobs but I would prefer not mixing them to make it cleaner*

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but this should work from my understanding. Saving the file to an artifact will restore it before `job2` starts. So it should be possible to append to the file.

Probably would test it with some simpler structure like this

```
job2: 
  script:
    - echo "ANOTHER_VARIABLE=${ANOTHER_VARIABLE}" >> job.env
  artifacts:
    paths:
        - job.env
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out